# Sentinel while loop displaying the sentinel value when it ends

Tags: python

```
total = 0
count = 0
grade = input("Enter the grade between 0 and 100 or type stop to display average: ")
        
while grade != "stop":
    x = float(grade)
    total += x
    count += 1
    grade = input("Enter the grade between 0 and 100 or type stop to display average: ")
    
average = total/count
print(f'\nYour average grade is {average}')
```

When I enter stop, I don't want stop to be printed next to the last input.

My current output is:

> Enter the grade between 0 and 100 or type stop to display average: 10
>
> Enter the grade between 0 and 100 or type stop to display average: 50
>
> Enter the grade between 0 and 100 or type stop to display average: 100
>
> Enter the grade between 0 and 100 or type stop to display average: stop
>
> Your average grade is 53.333333333333336

Comment: `stop` is not being printed, you have typed it in response to the `input()` call.

Comment: can it not display `stop` when I enter as an input. Like using an if conditional or something or there is nothing wrong with this type of code.

Comment: you can use `curses` library for that.

Comment: If you really need to hide it, and are running this in a terminal which disables echo `powershell`, `shell` or `cmd` you could use `getpass.getpass` you would need to `import getpass`.

Comment: It's pretty uncommon to hide what the user is actually typing, except for passwords.  You don't want to hide the numbers that are typed, right?  What if you type "stoop" instead of "stop"?  How can it know what to hide?  Maybe you should change the condition to `while grade != "":` and then simply hit return to stop.

Comment: @user2740650 you are right. If I use enter, the input would be an empty string I guess and it doesn't show. I was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good to practice 'don't repeat yourself' style. Also to be little defensive while taking user input - what should happen if user enters something which can't be converted into float?

One can repeatedly ask for grades and try to convert answer into float and perform calculation. If user input can't be converted into float then check whether it's 'stop' - if so print average and break else print that entered value is not allowed.

```
total = 0
count = 0

while True: 
    grade = input('Enter the grade between 0 and 100 or type "stop" to display average: ') 
    try: 
        total += float(grade)                  
        count += 1 
    except ValueError: 
        if grade.lower() == 'stop': 
            print(f'Your average grade is {total/count:.2f}') 
            break 
        else: 
            print(f'Input {grade!r} is not allowed')
```